# Swinging onto a Hill

Tags: momentum, velocity, collision, free-fall

I was just watching the movie "Frozen" (not the Disney one), and they were trapped in a ski lift 50 feet off the ground.  They had to jump.  My question is, when they jump, should they swing on the lift towards up the hill or down the hill?  If they swing up the hill, it will be a shorter drop.  If they swing down the hill, they will not have such a hard collision.

Physics is not my thing, and I am just looking for a general answer, so any variable you can just assume to be "generic".  I guess the slope of the hill is 45 degrees and the swinging momentum is...whatever.

```
\
 \      o
  \  <-   ->
   \
    \
     \
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be safer to swing closer to the hill if I am understanding your question. I've never seen the movie you are talking about but, in general, a lesser height would provide a smaller time frame in which the jumpers would accelerate. A lower impact velocity would result in a higher chance of withstanding the crash.

Comment: This is the naively correct answer, but note that ski jumpers land safely on a hill that slopes *away* from them after making every effort to fall as far as possible, and part of what makes that possible is hitting the snow with the largest component of their velocity directed *along* rather than *into* the surface.

Comment: How do they angle themselves to fall parallel to the slope? Or is it that they jump to fall further so they land on a part of the slope that is steeper?

Comment: For ski jumpers the design of the jump mostly controls the landing geometry. In the scenario the OP offers the victims have pretty minimal control. I suspect that for many cases the naive answer is correct here simply because without skis you can't take maximum advantage of the ski-jumping behavior. *"You want me to bend my knees and roll after falling **how** far?"* kind of thing.

Comment: Ah now I understand. The OP is looking at jumping off a ski lift not a ski jump. When you go off a jump you attempt to have a maximum velocity that is parallel to the slope. This makes it much easier to withstand the landing.